# Phaser 3 with Unity Ads

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, unityads, mraid

I am trying to make a playable on Unity Ads using Phaser 3 but it seems that there are multiple specifications to use it, one of the Unity Ads specifications and as in their documentation "Advertisements should be designed not to need any network requests (XHR), but for example, analytics calls to track user interaction are allowed"
So I don't know how to add the Phaser CDN to my file.
Note: the Playable should be in one file and images must be in base 64.
So I need to know if there is an example of how to make playable on unity ads using phaser 3.
The following code shows a black screen when I test it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>

    
    <script>
 
 class Test extends Phaser.Scene{
  constructor(){
    super('test')
       this.imageData = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAABwCAYAAADWrHjSAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAACy1JREFUeNrsXcGK20gQ7VnvdZnkE/IJ2j/QZTF7Euwt7HkhEAj45lOYk28DAwOBPS97C/gURC7+g9Un7CckZs/GCxmVwE9+etWyPHEmVZeJHUndkvVev6qurr7a7/fpKdnPV1eDN/TPfn91zvO/NfshhX3X9uNTQ/7ceRwi+dTzgwHCggEuAfnF7OFvuXv4u2k/N+3nORnrEfnsOmn3tJggGCAY4LLU+r/Pnn35++nTp6spkG+fE2GC5EQ+XieXCZ4/f/7luBefP1+UdxEMEAxwYWq9RYhXrasxPwkmSCdeRzGBff/qQr2LYIBggK+LfEOemVLryhDZ9rnM7O/Y63i9C3W/j8UEwQDBAF/HTzcrAWlMrdfk+sxPt+OX7ffXr399+Mf9h8H+Xr95OK5oj1tBP9AraMh1VFwB77ezR44zBAMEAzwO8heGoDSsrpVaT8AIyCg1ILDcjes/IrxrD5igFtdnyEcvw45bPLJ3EAwQDHAewzEQ3/gaxjxDfNWO1eXdh6P+NmqB1c7Xrl2vYZpid3gcaoo5aY/dNyLftMW61RbqOSQRsQwGCLssBrCxymL5LwARDUFwTRBoiGFMkIR/nYjWSALBbGxOoAGanW/Mt/vYCgbqMQF8/w7mEqbSBMEAwQDTqn2L5TNEFoIRcMxmTIAIpWp/NtweQ2DudRXyN4SB5oLBuucFs4hTeQfBAN+5XY3NClazcmaGBLMeIkBdKxW9BWbAz6n8vaWSv462x5hAtcuuq/rF2l2SiCh7XsqbGssEwQDBAPtJkb8hY5l6wzdklowisrvwITLXEOu3uAL1vwkD4Hl4PWyX3Q/zJnKfB543FRMEAwQD7CdB/i+AJIzJKz95LILY2JgEok89jrWfy2DsfhN5jvb540SaIBgg4gDT2BLe9IVAhkXEbN4dEYJ+P3oJyYm4zu+2MVvkA9hx1n7JGIa0X5PnQb0DEn8wWxAGSrtpfrdggNAA4zRAcnoBuWO1QgybjVsK/33928ujiO0hy9T++78H4wm5/VBjvVdb0KzlFBog7JwawN4oxgTsjfRm/ODYWrXIvbY3n2iCpYjZb6uXR9tj+QCGRDsPVTv2n/UDGWgz0qtoVA7hSOQHA4TlMQDmu6v5a8wDUBk/K1DtpSFw3Y7FEBPHnD9EnCGYIYll2vRyFS3Gvz7UBJhhxLwJ6wfmASydGUPe542/U2iAsGm8gNyVLmar3fDxxgQq8ocIedse313H1DqM+UptJ8UAzDtZH7Zn3oWdd/Nm3H0p5C9nvv7WRLsFA4TlaQDvWj6mvhuhCTDjByN0bC3eDSBQzft7+8tUdk8TgHdgDFRBfxhCzViuINNSKjMpEY2gNEEwQDBAHvK98/IW48d8/t4aO8z6JfGFjjHQz3eOtYg8Kt7B20gz4R2I/rCYPTsOn1OBaxvhOVdwvSRqIiETBAMEAwwbmydHpCASWCUNxiQqLoDIYxEzN1MRu2aMIJiA9Uf5/WzdA81KBs2D7VawCrrZRRwgzMMAKuOn56fOhsfOTiXbF+T8SnQQI2C9yBsgrcbjoF83or23d8fzBXqrgJ39UcYYrEMyjvFwXs/bgPwKVcsoGCAYYNjQT3/Xrv17hfXuCCN0kTOSicNUPObAKURhHQI29r+tXg5e5wZi/maLtp+3KQ/hbE5EeT9sToPFF+x3+fO/z4PxldAAYQfWzQXQih7w5v3x0yEDeP1t1BCFeKNVzB5NnU9X+hB1vXnk/o3VAHYeMgDeNzJXaICwBwYoUsqrvEniBCoXr3HW0unFEQijbIlaz825m+p875o+xgg0/iJyE72/C4tPBAOEF+BDAqr/U5Gfi3gcs6+JWi5hFlHl87Oxmq4vsPbRW2D9I3GSJBih+9w+R2MCliPJfid1v8EAoQHSYCVPpfpz897NMCNIzS6ysVWeRxhJrg5+TxB+an/gPMwIUl6D97kzryA0QJhPAyiVOnbFCzuvN0aydfJiDmKDaw1BYzTigXRjPqpujLETdY+Rt1J4K/b/FTwXtW5CZVQxTRMaIMzHAEr145ucW+PHq85VJdDkXH1ctaq9sDWChKmu27G/0wwJvACh3mvRv955mVXRVmQ2FWf/7HdjWiAYIGyYAZStST19mkcPKhgRUxOkLzPz+FkGThJagB1HM5SId1OQ/rHZw4JprPa5lbC2MSET3B/WMci1YIBggMM3FN9INpav2jFK1tcT6+tVpczcPP7Exsq2H7gjSIe414f99fbT2z/GDCuRbaxyB+38ih2XhjVKMMD3zgC47l+tZMGIFZ0lIxGwJhNRak6gwixZQBzmyuE8O9M2ze64BvHmFdA4xQzuG/z83lhu1787nutXQ85mJVZamUU+QNgX6zKCbG9b5j+yeoALwhCI5FunSpd5/KRW79iYO1ruHAXtB2EElieAWgP3DtqQVdX4XLF+IM7lvIO9mYMBggEO6wOw3ECFYJbf3pA1b73sXUDOFrJ3af39JMZoQF7unAU7X7XbmyUUq5rx+aJGYnkKikFYLmB4AWGHcYCxpmLX7I3GCp6IeDbL1ovNs7jA/fAqX1YlzHs+Gs499GYtkdGg9lHBdkdTax5V5VNhwQDBAMMRo8K5jx2LXdeqQoZz5UsicYOUfOexSFjv+8zsZXf7hBEUkr1zK6xuYx2rg8NGMQCrEELfcDLbR/cUasf+27sPg8iTkUJQ1xXsHNJkrtZlmqW3UwjxVmh+wu64ZriB6uRyf0PynNnzUruvBwMEA/jGxAW8uegfq9o7OPbbm4xrEGWNn/XxuoAYT8C6BN51+xL5GAGE/pSEEeh9wSylV9VvyawfWwsYGiDstDjAZuROFSzPwF1JE1UvyS/oVe0SY6t330C1DyGqeWSiklQrp9m94rlN/TsFAwQDHBrmB6CqxDfTuz6AagYy5rGMokQ0g8qosXbYnjt4nyqjSVULY+3TeAgZ073rAfB3KSAOEJVCw8ZpAFnRA7JSmd+NGS/bu+MZLKwyxkbs0sVi+d3+BGJnUxZnWN8Pz3EkUTWtq5b2+vh9IrOpfQJK6BedmwgNEDapF8Dy5FEL1O0bvRSzbwvGBJnIn6v+wt5Dys/uqXjSjzlBqDHlZjbMBIh8lQ+wgv0IcOzH/IwmBQOEOcy9Y8hS7BVcOPe3q8V5bCxjES25LgHyDViErJeptPbV5vH2y3t/3l3Z8TzMBVwJ9R8MEJanAdAf/QhMUKTjCFSRuFrsLVSICB5T46yev9smRr5aRayYDLWI2kXca8EAwQB5hv78ElfPzobjAwwxSY3lYgcSb+VOGQnc5Z2v8gfUTh4qXoJxCNypNO3GIT8YIMzHAGzPYFPTtr/9iiF9dngcy1UrRIwdI4Y1qauXW8N3LAMyZvDuh6jWJagxHef9UVvEzqFh59EAvZ0sd0QLgDovydiPKp6p+kr0R9XlV4jKPU9l2mzE3IGKZDJvY0n2FlqFBgg7KwOwOgIN0QI4F6Bm4VQkjM1+efcyZu0lgUSmUZDBvHv2eJmDMWtv7Cfr/oMBws6jAZhXYG/uElRqV7X7zDeSXbvHaajKi5ERt1xbEC20IVoiF/nBAGHjGIAxQS+m79zvXvrbmKULcQS2fkGqcaYJSLsq3z7Xj2f3i/kEyisYi/xggLDTGIC9gcYI6cRVunNn+6zW0G3KU9+MCRoYkxdpnP/tvV/GGPVEiA8GCDswmRF0qnWMkMsgIi6wERkzTHN41waquILqh3fMzn0+U1swQDDA/iI7xpiA+f9qtq3ObH8+sh3W3rmRHAwQ9rQYwMsIzGtQiM8di+dCvX8riA8GCPs2GSDXuzhVTZ/7+sEAYRdh/wswAEUzF3/Fcfl2AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC';
       this.brain = null;

  }

 
  create () {
    
    

this.textures.addBase64('brain', this.imageData);

this.textures.once('addtexture', function () {

this.brain = this.add.sprite(this.wid, 300, 'brain');
this.brain.setInteractive()
this.brain.on('pointerdown',()=>{
    
    mraid.open('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=[name of a game]')
   })
}, this);




  //  this.btn = this.add.image(400, 300, 'btn')
  //  .setScale(0.3)



 }
}
 


    

// Wait for the SDK to become ready
if (mraid.getState() === 'loading') {
  mraid.addEventListener('ready', onSdkReady);
  } else {
  onSdkReady();
  }
  function viewableChangeHandler(viewable) {
  // start/pause/resume gameplay, stop/play sounds
  if(viewable) {
   showMyAd();
  } else {
   // pause
  }
  }
  function onSdkReady() {
  mraid.addEventListener('viewableChange', viewableChangeHandler);
  // Wait for the ad to become viewable for the first time
  if (mraid.isViewable()) {
   showMyAd();
  }
  }
  function showMyAd() {
    
    const config = {
      type: Phaser.AUTO,
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
          gravity: { y: 200 }
        }
      },
      scene:[Test]
    };
    new Phaser.Game(config);
  }
  </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: did my answer solve your issue? if so please accept it. Or if you found a better solution you could also share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know how **unity ads** works, but you could simply **inline** the minified *phaser-code-file* into a `script`-tag above the gamecode, and so there are no calls to external source / cdn's.

```
...
<script> !function(t,e){"object"==typeof exports&& ... </script>
...
```

(This will obviously increase your html-file significantly ***(~ 1 MB)***, but works)

> ***Tip:** if you are using a bundler like *[webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or so*, this could be done automatically, maybe even images an such.*